# accessing RSA Key from another server

Tags: php, ssh, rsa

Part of my decryption process is using a RSA private key to decrypt part of my data. I store my private RSA Key on a separate server (as well as the password for the private RSA Key) from where I process the decryption request.

Decryption of information in my SQL database happens a lot. So I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to grab my key and the password to the key so I don't bog down the server too much.

**note: *I do not know how much strain this puts on a server so I may be completely wrong***

Right now, the only way I can think about doing it is SSH'ing into the server and grabbing the file contents and then closing the request.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Something along the lines of this:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('domain.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$file = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why u store ur RSA key and password on another server because if your Server can access them using any way, a hacker can do the same thing. In your code, the hacker just need to SSH into the server using the hardcoded username and password.

In case of SSH connection, it is also not a good idea put them into part of web request ( I assume it is  a web application since I saw PHP :) ). SSH connection takes a huge amount of time to establish.

A lighter solution is to create a https web server on your RSA key server and only white list your Web server ip address. It is same encryption as SSH (SSL) but much faster.

Again, it seems not necessary to put the RSA key and password on another server according to your scenario.

Comment: I've already whitelisted my server but what else would you suggest if I don't want to buy another ssl cert

Comment: You do not need to buy a certified SSL. Because it is only for your private usage. A certified SSL is mostly for public use for safer communication and public trust. You could just use self signed SSL which is totally free. There are a lot of tools out there.